# How are fluids implemented in tools like Blender?

Tags: blender-2.76

I can't find any help in creating very complicated shapes like water in internet. 
How it is possible to simulate that complex thing like water in computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t accurately simulate fluids in Blender. The built in physics engine allows you to get something that **looks good** but is limited in accuracy. For graphics purposes the Blender physics engine is great, but for engineering applications it’s less reliable.

Accurate fluid modelling techniques are known as  Computational Fluid Dynamics(CFD).

It’s possible to combine Blender with CFD [see DualSPHysics](https://wiki.manchester.ac.uk/sphysics/images/Blender_for_SPHysics_v2.2_GUIDE.pdf) which is awesome.

CFD is fascinating, [watch what NVIDIA and SpaceX have done](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=txk-VO1hzBY).  But actually testing and scale tests in wind tunnels /tanks still have a place.